Are there any disadvantages of pre-publishing figures for a paper separatly using a CC-BY license?
I recently came across a blog post, where it was suggested to pre-publish figures you intend to use in an academic paper somewhere using a CC-BY license. I find this idea really nice (as it allows easy re-use of my figures, without checking the journal's copyright policy), and never really thought about it for my papers but am considering to do it for my next paper. However, I have realized that nobody from my community is doing this (or even heard of it before), so I have the impression that this very uncommon. Am I missing something, apart from the extra work to publish the figures (i.e. uploading them to some repository), are there any further disadvantages?
I also found a second example where somebody is doing this, but that's not my field (and in general, this procedure seems to be very rare in academic research)

Related answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/123912/17254

How many times do you think you will actually reuse the exact same figure? Why complicate things?

@JonCuster to clarify: these figures are illustrating the general mechanism of a diagnostics, so I have the naive idea of them being of some value (realistically to only a small number of people though...)

This depends on the field, and, more specifically, on publishers in that field. Some publishers won't publish anything for which they won't hold copyright as it can reduce the value of the publication to them. A problem with figures is that they can convey a lot of information and, thus, be considered to have a lot of value.
In math that would probably not be a problem, but in some other fields, with some other publishers, it might be.
I suggest you look at the pre-publication policies of a few reputable journals in your field and act accordingly.
The trend seems to be toward the more permissive in such things, but it isn't yet entirely open. Look before you jump.

Will some publishers seriously not allow to include CC-BY material in their papers...? Wow, I wasn't aware of that (I'm in physics)...

@Alf It's common to see guidelines such as "Reproduction of previously published figures, tables, and text should be kept to a minimum and must be properly referenced and comply with the copyright or licensing requirements of the paper’s publisher.". How the "previously published" and "minimum" are interpreted in practice is not clearly stated and left to the publisher's discretion. But, in general, such policies may limit how far you can take your approach.

@Anyon thanks for showing that example, and that is indeed a very vague expression...

@Alf The entire issue only arises because some publishers seriously do not allow reusing parts of "their" papers, as you know. That they don’t allow obvious workarounds shouldn’t be all that surprising.
